# Binary tree changing root

Tags: python, binary-tree

I'm starting to study binary trees, and found this code in a teaching website

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):

        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

    def insert(self, data):
# Compare the new value with the parent node
        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data

# Print the tree
    def PrintTree(self):
        if self.left:
            self.left.PrintTree()
        print( self.data),
        if self.right:
            self.right.PrintTree()

# Use the insert method to add nodes
root = Node(27)
root.insert(14)
root.insert(35)
root.insert(31)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(19)


root.PrintTree()
```

And after debugging said code, i noticed that the correct root value was set at the beggining, but after a few steps changed to another value.
At the end, the root value was set with the correct int (the first value), but i can't understand why.

Also, is there a better way to create a binary tree and insert values in python?

Comment: In that code, the `root` node will never change.  What leads you to think it did?

Comment: That's a perfectly fine way to create a binary tree.  If the data are sorted, it will produce a very tall and skinny tree; solving that problem requires rebalancing, which is hard.  There are existing binary tree modules available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're being fooled by the debugger.  After the first three statements, you'll have three objects:  One named `root`, one named `root.left`, one named `root.right`:

```
root.data = 27
root.left.data = 14
root.right.data = 35
```

If you were then tracing through inserting 31, you'd get to the part in `insert` where it calls `self.right.insert(data)`.  At that point, you'll start `insert` again, but now `self` is the node in `root.right`.  It's not `root` any more.